# React Native release app crashes with FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context

Tags: react-native

I create the signings for my release app, put them inside `android/app/` and inside `android/app/build.gradle` do the following:

```java
signingConfigs {
    release {
            keyAlias 'my-key-alias'
            keyPassword 'mypassword'
            storeFile file('mykeystore.keystore')
            storePassword 'mypassword'
        }
}
```

And inside the buildTypes:

```java
buildTypes {
    release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
            }
        }
}
```

When I run `react-native run-android --variant=release` the app is installed successfully on my emulator but when I open it, it crashes! I opened the logcats in Android Studio and this is what is printed out:

```
--------- beginning of crash
2020-08-12 18:53:51.069 5909-5957/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
    Process: com.encarti.mobile.worker, PID: 5909
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:789)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:639)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:577)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:525)
        at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.<clinit>(HermesExecutor.java:20)
        at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory.create(HermesExecutorFactory.java:29)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:997)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Something is telling me that it has to do with a library or something. I am using `react-native-config` for handling my environment variables, I am also using using Firebase so I have a `google-services.json` inside `android/app/`. I don't know what else may be causing the error!

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Getting the same error after generating APK file, did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @lordcarnisser Yes... Although it was totally unrelated. For some reason, `console.dir` was causing the problem.

Comment: I'm facing this issue too

Answer (score 3):

THis is caused by enabling `Hermes`.

```
couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
```

1 - Always clean your gradle build before building your app.

2 - If you use custom builts Variants ex `stagingRelease`, don't forget to add custom implementation on your `/app/build.gradle`

```
if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    stagingReleaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```

Comment: I have hermes disabled, clean before every build, and this still happens.

Answer (score 2):

If you have other build variants (e.g. staging), like I did, you need to add `bundleInStaging: true` (or equivalent) to `project.ext.react` into your app-level `build.gradle`.

[See this full answer](https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native/issues/269#issuecomment-437603077). For me, this simple thing took me more than 6 hours to find out, not kidding.

Answer (score 0):

If you're gradle/plugin versions are above 4.1.0/6.5 and on react native 0.63.3 - this is a known issue that is fixed on RN version 0.63.4

`Fix App Bundle/Release build missing index.android.bundle with gradle plugin 4.1.0/gradle 6.5 (53f55001af by @tomoima525)`

https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0634